# How to use a javascript file in a level up folder?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm not a professional in programming and somehow can't get any further. 
I'm trying to change the value of an attribute depending on which dropdown content the user selected. 
The javascript file has to be one level up, because in this file I start the node.js server.

My file structure is:

Folder: MyFirstProgramm

- index.js
- Folder: public --> index.html

Thus, I want to use the code I programmed in index.js in index.html

When I use the option script in the html file, I do not have access to the result in index.js.

I've tried any imports, but nothing worked.

This is my html file (index.html):

```
<h1>...</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../index.js"></script>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Please select any group
                <br>
                <br>
                <select name="group" id="group" onchange="getSelectValue();">
                    <option id="">-- select group --</option>
                    <option value="Gruppe 1" id="G1">group 1</option>
                    <option value="Gruppe 2" id="G2">group 2</option>
                    <option value="Gruppe 3" id="G3">group 3</option>
                    <option value="Gruppe 4" id="G4">group 4</option>
                    <option value="Gruppe 5" id="G5">group 5</option>
                </select>


            </label>
        </form>
```

and my script code (in index.js):

```
function getSelectValue() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("group").value;
    var api;
    if (selectedValue == "Gruppe 1") {
        api = "XXXXXXXX";
    }
    if (selectedValue == "Gruppe 2") {
        api = "XXXXXXXX";
    }
    if (selectedValue == "Gruppe 3") {
        api = "Nicht definiert!";
    }
    if (selectedValue == "Gruppe 4") {
        api = "Nicht definiert!";
    }
    if (selectedValue == "Gruppe 5") {
        api = "Nicht definiert!";
    }
    console.log(selectedValue);
    console.log(api);

    return api;
}


var apiKey = api;
```

Could you please help me??
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: if `public` is the root folder of the HTTP server, then you can't access "above" it

Comment: How about going some more levels up? Maybe let the browser download `../../../../etc/passwd`?